# GCM With Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have implemented GCM with Xamarin.ios , I am able to get Device Token and GCM ID , But i am not able to recive Notification sent by Push sharp library . I am seeing log and i am getting below issue.Can this be reason of not receiving notification ?. Also we are new in Xamarin ,It will be hlpful if somebody can help us with podfile.

**You have enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/CloudMessaging" or you may need to run `pod update` in your project directory.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosgcm) component and implement it in your `AppDelegate` There are code examples of how to do so in the [Getting Started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiosgcm) section.

Comment: Hello Thanks ,I have added component and able to get GCM ID and device token, But i am not able to receive notification sent by server . When i see log i am seeing below message even i am getting GCM id.You have enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/CloudMessaging" or you may need to run pod update in your project directory.

Comment: DidReceiveRemoteNotification or ReceivedRemoteNotification never called. never called with apns also /

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this component and implement it in your AppDelegate There are code examples of how to do so in the Getting Started section.